# AW_Blog Extension: Trying To Create A URL Rewrite To A Blog Post

Tags: url-rewrite

I use the AW_Blog extension for my blog posts and am trying to do an internal URL rewrite through Magento's Catalog->"URL Rewrite Management" menu.

The URL of the blog post looks like this:

```
www.site.com/store-name/blog-route/cat/category-name/post/full-post-name
```

and I would like the URL

```
www.site.com/short-post-name
```

to point to it.

So far, I have two custom rewrite rules. The first does a 301 redirect from

```
www.site.com/short-post-name
```

to

```
www.site.com/store-name/short-post-name
```

This one works fine. For the second, I have an internal (no redirect) rewrite from

```
www.site.com/store-name/short-post-name
```

to

```
www.site.com/store-name/blog-route/cat/category-name/post/full-post-name
```

This one, however, does not work unless I add the 301 redirect, which leaves the long and ugly URL in the address bar (and defeats much of the point of the rewrite).

I think the problem lies in the fact that the blog posts are not static pages, but rather served through a controller action, similar to category and product pages (which get their own rewrite options).

Does anyone know of a way that I can achieve this rewrite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These internal rewrites are only implemented for [categories and products](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Url/Rewrite.php#L57-L59), you cannot define them for arbitrary controllers.

So if the extension does not have a mechanism for it, you would need to write your own custom router.